# Mutex can't acquire lock

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex

I have a problem where one of my functions can't aquire the lock on one of the 2 mutexes I use.
I did a basic debug in VC++2010 , setting some breakpoints and it seems if anywhere the lock is acquired, it does get unlocked.

The code that uses mutexes is as follow:

```
#define SLEEP(x) { Sleep(x); }
#include<windows.h>

    void Thread::BackgroundCalculator( void *unused ){
    while( true ){
        if(MUTEX_LOCK(&mutex_q, 5) == 1){
            if(!QueueVector.empty()){
//cut
                MUTEX_UNLOCK(&mutex_q);
                    //cut
                while(MUTEX_LOCK(&mutex_p,90000) != 1){}
                //cut
                MUTEX_UNLOCK(&mutex_p);
            }

        }
        SLEEP(25);
    }
}
```

Then somwhere else:

```
PLUGIN_EXPORT void PLUGIN_CALL
    ProcessTick(){
    if(g_Ticked == g_TickMax){
        if(MUTEX_LOCK(&mutex_p, 1) == 1){
            if(!PassVector.empty()){
                PassVector.pop();
            }
            MUTEX_UNLOCK(&mutex_p);
        }
        g_Ticked = -1;
    }
    g_Ticked += 1;
}
```

---

```
static cell AMX_NATIVE_CALL n_CalculatePath( AMX* amx, cell* params ){
    if(MUTEX_LOCK(&mutex_q,1) == 1){
        QueueVector.push_back(QuedData(params[1],params[2],params[3],amx));
        MUTEX_UNLOCK(&mutex_q);
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

init:

```
PLUGIN_EXPORT bool PLUGIN_CALL Load( void **ppData ) {
    MUTEX_INIT(&mutex_q);
    MUTEX_INIT(&mutex_p);
    START_THREAD( Thread::BackgroundCalculator, 0);
    return true;
}
```

Some variables and functions:

```
int MUTEX_INIT(MUTEX *mutex){
    *mutex = CreateMutex(0, FALSE, 0);
    return (*mutex==0);
}

int MUTEX_LOCK(MUTEX *mutex, int Timex = -1){
    if(WaitForSingleObject(*mutex, Timex) == WAIT_OBJECT_0){
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
int MUTEX_UNLOCK(MUTEX *mutex){
    return ReleaseMutex(*mutex);
}

MUTEX mutex_q = NULL;
MUTEX mutex_p = NULL;
```

and defines:

```
#   include <process.h>
#   define OS_WINDOWS
#   define MUTEX HANDLE
#   include <Windows.h>
#   define EXIT_THREAD() { _endthread(); }
#   define START_THREAD(a, b) { _beginthread( a, 0, (void *)( b ) ); }
```

Thread header file:

```
#ifndef __THREAD_H
#define __THREAD_H

class Thread{
    public:
                                    Thread                      ( void );
                                   ~Thread                      ( void );
    static void                     BackgroundCalculator        ( void *unused );

};

#endif
```

Well I can't seem to find the issue.
After debugging I wanted to "force" aquiring the lock by this code (from the pawn abstract machine):

```
if (strcmp("/routeme", cmdtext, true) == 0){
    new fromnode = NearestPlayerNode(playerid);
    new start = GetTickCount();
    while(CalculatePath(fromnode,14,playerid+100) == 0){
        printf("0 %d",fromnode);
    }
    printf("1 %d",fromnode);
    printf("Time: %d",GetTickCount()-start);
    return 1;
}
```

but it keeps endless going on, CalculatePath calls static cell AMX_NATIVE_CALL n_CalculatePath( AMX* amx, cell* params )

That was a bit of surprise. Does anyone maybe see a mistake?

If you need the full source code it is available at:

http://gpb.googlecode.com/files/RouteConnector_174alpha.zip

Extra info:
PLUGIN_EXPORT bool PLUGIN_CALL Load 
gets only executed at startup.

static cell AMX_NATIVE_CALLs
get only executed when called from a vitrual machine

ProcessTick()
gets executed every process tick of the application, after it has finished its own jobs it calls this one in the extensions.

For now I only tested the code on windows, but it does compile fine on linux.

Edit: removed linux code to shorten post.

Comment: That's a lot of code... can you cut it down to something more manageable? Try removing code until you can no longer reproduce the problem and when that happens only submit the code that's just enough to reproduce the problem. It would be best if you can provide a http://sscce.org/ compliant example.

Comment: I did my best and removed almost all things not related to the threads.

Comment: Hmm, kinda looks like this question dropped very low in the 'unanswered' list? ; o

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I see your first snippet unlocks mutex based on some condition only, i.e. in pseudocode it is like:

```
mutex.lock ():
if some_unrelated_thing:
    mutex.unlock ()
```

As I understand your code, this way the first snippet can in principle lock and then never unlock.

Another potential problem is that your code is ultimately exception-unsafe.  Are you really able to *guarantee* that no exceptions happen between lock/unlock operations?  Because if any uncaught exception is ever thrown, you get into a deadlock like described.  I'd suggest using some sort of RAII here.

**EDIT:**

Untested RAII way of performing lock/unlock:

```
struct Lock
{
  MUTEX&  mutex;
  bool    locked;

  Lock (MUTEX& mutex)
    : mutex (mutex),
      locked (false)
  { }

  ~Lock ()
  { release (); }

  bool acquire (int timeout = -1)
  {
    if (!locked && WaitForSingleObject (mutex, timeout) == WAIT_OBJECT_0)
      locked = true;
    return locked;
  }

  int release ()
  {
    if (locked)
      locked = ReleaseMutex (mutex);
    return !locked;
  }
};
```

Usage could be like this:

```
{
  Lock  q (mutex_q);
  if (q.acquire (5)) {
      if (!QueueVector.empty ()) {
          q.release ();
          ...
      }
  }
}
```

Note that this way `~Lock` always releases the mutex, whether you did that explicitly or not, whether the scope block exited normally or due to an uncaught exception.

Comment: indeed that was the problem. Bit of shame I didn't see it. Anyway the bounty can be given in 22 h, so stay tuned..
ByTheWay about RAII, could you give an example (with my code?)

Comment: @Rafal Grasman: See the edit in the answer.  You could also try using Boost, that additionally provides portability and saves from writing (and testing) your own code.

Comment: Ah now I Understand that too :] Thank you.
And yeah soon I will re-make my projects with boost.

Comment: 10 h remaining before the bounty can be given, Kinda stupid to wait when a solution is accepted =D

Comment: I think that's because you can post bounties on questions you didn't ask, so the two aren't guaranteed to be linked.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is intended behavior, but in this code:

```
void Thread::BackgroundCalculator( void *unused ){
while( true ){
    if(MUTEX_LOCK(&mutex_q, 5) == 1){
        if(!QueueVector.empty()){
            //cut
            MUTEX_UNLOCK(&mutex_q);
            //cut
            while(MUTEX_LOCK(&mutex_p,90000) != 1){}
            //cut
            MUTEX_UNLOCK(&mutex_p);
        }
    }
    SLEEP(25);
}
```

if the `QueueVector.empty` is true you are never unlocking `mutex_q`.

Comment: Yeah that's the code that was problematic I see, the poster before you was a bit earlier heh.

Comment: Yeah, he was really fast, considering I saw the question immediately. :)